# Does the sequence of iterated derivatives of $2^x$ converge uniformly to the zero function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the function $2^x$. As you keep taking derivatives of that function over and over again, it converges to the zero function, at least pointwise. My question is, does it converge uniformly to the zero function on the entire real line? I used the example of $2^x$, but I could have used any exponential function $b^x$ for a number $b$ between $1$ and $e$.

Comment: The sequence of functions in the question is explicitly found as $f_n(x) = 2^x (\ln 2)^n$, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Abstracting the question: let $f(x)$ be any unbounded function, and let $a_n$ be any sequence tending to $0$; then the functions $f_n(x) = a_nf(x)$ tend to $0$ pointwise. Do you think this sequence converges uniformly to the $0$ function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $\frac{d}{dx} b^x = b^x \ln b$, just multiplying by a constant.  (If $b = e$, then that constant is $\ln e = 1$, so the function is its own derivative.)  With each iterated differentiation, you just multiply by the same constant again, so:

$$f_n(x) = (\ln b)^nb^x$$

This converges (pointwise) to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$ if $|\ln b| < 1$, ie.,

$$\frac{1}{e} < b < e$$

It happens that $b = 2$ satisfies this condition.

However, *uniform* convergence on the entire real line requires

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, n \ge N: |f_n(x) - 0| < \epsilon$$
$$|\ln b|^nb^x < \epsilon$$
$$|\ln b|^n < \frac{\epsilon}{b^x}$$

which cannot be satisfied $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ unless $|\ln b| = 0$ (IOW, $b = 1$).