# Does the sequence of iterated derivatives of $2^x$ converge uniformly to the zero function on any interval that is bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

This is a follow-up to my previous question, here: [Does the sequence of iterated derivatives of $2^x$ converge uniformly to the zero function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513286/does-the-sequence-of-iterated-derivatives-of-2x-converge-uniformly-to-the-zer). In that question, it was proven that the sequence of iterated derivatives of $2^x$ does not converge uniformly to the zero function over the entire real line. However, does it converge uniformly to the zero function over any interval $(-\infty, a)$? I am pretty sure it does, but I want to see a proof. And, as with my previous question, I used the specific example of the exponential function $2^x$, but I could have used any exponential function $b^x$ with $1 < b < e$.

Comment: In the interval $(-\infty,a]$ the $n$th derivative is uniformly bounded from above by $(\ln 2)^n2^a$. What happens to that bound when $n\to\infty$?